# Is an object a data structure?

Tags: object, data-structures

I know things like arrays, linked lists, etc are data structures...but what about objects?

Like say if I create an object say employee and it stores and keeps track of the employees name, salary, phone number...etc etc.

Comment: That mostly depends on the specific language you're talking about and what its definition of an "object" is. If it means a *key-value* association, as it often does, then yes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can think this through yourself... If you have a bunch of lawn equipment in your yard, and you decide to build a shed in which to store it, is that a structure? Why would constructing an object to collect all of the employee information be any different than building that shed?

Comment: JSON is a object and it is data structure you can say.

Answer (score 1):

It's a question of semantics really, and I expect it could be argued either way. 
When you create an object, you are telling a compiler, or an interpreter to store a group of information together. Usually the interpreter/compiler, will use some type of data structure to store that information (Python uses a hash table for example).

I might call that data structure the object if I pointed it out in a hex dump, but that's just because saying 'the bytes that represents the object' is a bit inconvenient.

You could (and maybe someone has) write a compiler that stores many objects in one data structure. In that case there would be no one to one mapping between object and data structure. So for that reason - I'm going to say no, an object is not a data structure, but it is normally stored in one.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, before [the OOP paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)  came into vogue, languages like C used `struct`'s (structures).  Which, in C is simply a contiguous block of virtual memory with named offsets (members).  Although that does get more complex with things like `unions`, etc.

But essentially a *structure*, as [@James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979576/james) pointed out, is exactly that - some collection or grouping of related *things* together in a way a programmer (or mad scientist) feels is logical.

In the modern programming lexicon, with languages such as Java, C#, etc - your Objects usually represent **one** *real-world* thing, such as a Customer, Order, < inset over-used object example here>, etc.  While your data-structures (usually *collections* in the libraries of the languages I mentioned) represent the **containment** of ***multiple*** "Objects".

Strictly speaking, however (and just to confuse everyone), the *data structures* in languages like Java and C# *are **objects**!*  (*i.e.* they are referenced passed around, can have methods called on them, etc.)

In a more classical (and perhaps more [CS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science) derived) sense, "data structures" are collections of behaviours (typically algorithms) that are used to manage the memory that *stores* **data**, while "objects" ***are*** that data.